# Versioning machine specific configs

Tags: git, mercurial, github, bitbucket

I want to work from several locations on -for instance- a website.
Every pc has its own repository of the project (preferably Mercurial, Git otherwise), but each computer needs its own config settings for testing locally, like base_url.
What is the best way of versioning this config file which will include global config settings as well?

Repository details:

1. Repo on BitBucket with config.php: global config + config for live server
2. Repo pc A with config.php: global config + config specific for pc A
3. Repo pc B with config.php: global config + config specific for pc B

When I checkout BitBucket repository I get the full live server configuration. If I need to make adjustments and test it locally, I change the live settings to the pc specific settings. Then fix a bug or whatever, commit and push to BitBucket.
At this moment the pc specific settings will get pushed to the global BitBucket repo: not what I want.

So what's the best method to get this done properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with php, but I assume you could have a global config.php file which could include (require?) `config.<hostname>.php` files. This way all the config files would be under version control, but there would be no conflicts. PHP should have some way of determining the hostname of the current machine and then loading the appropriate config file.

The resulting repository layout might look like this

```
/
/config.php
/config.web_server.php
/config.pc_A.php
/config.pc_B.php
```

Comment: Possible solution, yes, but I don't really want a config.pc_A.php floating aroung on my Live server. I know I could delete it just like that, but maaaaybe there's something better available. Thanks anyway

Comment: In that case, why not use a branch for each machine? `git cherry-pick` allows you to pull specific commits from other branches/remotes. I'm sure mercurial has a similar command, although I haven't used it enough to know what it is.

Comment: Nice, will look into that. It will be a little harder to pull (need to keep track of new commits), but at least a nice clean environment. Thanks again

Comment: Actually, will something like Git rebase work? Branch -> First commit will be pc specific -> rebase -> commit as usual

Comment: Not a bad solution at all. You could have config.php on separate branches for your PCs and when you want to fix something, create new branch and then rebase your fixes to e.g. master and push up master.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a smudge clean script that changes the config depending on what machine you are on.

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_keyword_expansion

If you want to track each PC's config in a separate branch, do the change to the config, then do a merge of your changes into the branch you have exposed in the common remote, but ignoring your change

```
git merge --no-ff -s ours yourbranch
```

From now on you can merge from your branch but your config change won't ever be merged as it is already considered having been merged according to the DAG.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is extremely helpful, especially http://progit.org/book/ch7-2.html#merge_strategies

Answer (score 0):

I would design config.php to be transparent. The repository itself shouldn't have to care about in what environment it's running on. I don't know what you need to change in order to get this up and running in your case, but perhaps lift out functionality from your config.php into some settings that is in turn read by config.php.

Comment: You mean separating global config and machine specific in different files, like Eric suggested? Possible, but not ideal (different config files on the live server which aren't needed). Thanks for the answer!